# How to customize workflow in the app?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin

Is it possbile to use an external workflow in a sharepoint provider hosted app?
We can only design the workflow in Visual Studio, but our customer wants to use the existing workflow, which is designed by Nintex. 
Could we import the workflow in the host web and use it in the app web. It seems to be impossible? or not?

Thanks very much.

Comment: on prem or office 365? Nintex fully supproted on office 365 app

Comment: Both of them, because we have the provider hosted app. But what do you mean "Nintex fully supported on O365 app"? How can the App call the workflow from Nintex? Thanks.

Comment: this is what i am talking about http://en-us.nintex.com/workflow-platform/nintex-products#Office-365

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think Nintex 365 could create a workflow inside the AppWeb.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a Host Workflow from an App is nothing but a huge pain. It requires several technical ID, as it depends on Azure workers to start.

Did you ask this question to your Nintex contact ? He should have more customer cases.

Last time I faced this choice, not from Nintex but SP2013 WorkFlow, I've simply been dealing with workflow processes in managed code. So I could finally get rid of headache =D

Comment: Thanks. I'm preferred to use SP2013 WF in App. But it is impossible to customize the workflow. All of them are dealed with code.